# How to hook into Laravel request errors prior to sending to view? Any way to limit to unique errors?

Tags: php, laravel

I created a custom FormRequest that will validate requests sent from the user answering a survey.

I defined my `rules()` method and overwrote the `messages()` method to customize the messages to tell the users that they must answer every question.

```
public function rules()
    {
        $client = $this->route('client');

        $rules = [
          'answer' => ['required','array', function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            $question_ids = array_keys($value);
            $questions_found = Question::whereIn('id', $question_ids)->count();
            if ($questions_found != count($question_ids))
              return $fail( __('You answered a question that does not exist.'));  // -> "quantity is invalid"
          }],
          'answer.*' => ['in:1,2,3,4'],
          'notes.*' => ['max:65535']
        ];

        foreach( $client->questions as $question ) {
            $rules['answer.'.$question->id] = ['required'];
        }

        return $rules;
    }

public function messages() {

    $messages = [
        'answer.required' => __( 'You must answer every question.' ),
        'answer.*' => __( 'You must answer every question with the multiple choices available.' ),
        'notes.*' => __( 'The length of your notes have exceeded the notes length limit.' )
    ];

    return $messages;
}
```

The problem that I currently have is that if a user submits the page without answer 5 questions then they see 5 duplicate error messages telling them to answer all questions. Currently I highlight the questions that aren't answered via a red outline but I would like an overview at the top of the page without the duplicate messages:

> You must answer every question.
>
> You must answer every question with the multiple choices available.
>
> You must answer every question with the multiple choices available.
>
> You must answer every question with the multiple choices available.
>
> You must answer every question with the multiple choices available.

If I don't define the `answer.*` rule then I get an error that is even less helpful:

> You must answer every question.
>
> The answer.18 field is required.
>
> The answer.10 field is required.
>
> The answer.5 field is required.
>
> The answer.8 field is required.

So basically I'm looking for a method I can override where I could take the errors and basically filter out the duplicates. I've googled but everything redirects me towards what I've already done (defining custom error messages).

Edit:

**I WAS ABLE TO DO WHAT I WANT WITH THE FOLLOWING:**

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) {
  $errors = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $validator->errors()->getMessages())));

  throw new HttpResponseException($this->response(
    $errors
  ));
}


public function response(array $errors) {
  if ($this->ajax() || $this->wantsJson())
  {
    return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
  }
  return $this->redirector->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
                                      ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
                                      ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag);
}
```

Thanks to the help of @Ryan J Field I was able to do it with overwriting the functions above. Unfortunately this had the unintended consequence of removing the answers that were wrong so my template couldn't outline them. The easiest way to solve this, for my situation, is to filter the duplicates in the blade template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use the `bail` rule to stop after one validation failure?

Or alternatively override the [failedValidation](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.html#method_failedValidation) method to customise what happens on a validation failure?

Default Behaviour:

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw (new ValidationException($validator))
                    ->errorBag($this->errorBag)
                    ->redirectTo($this->getRedirectUrl());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this ended up leading me to what I wanted but then I discovered that by filtering out duplicate answers I was also unsetting the attributes -- meaning I couldn't outline each unanswered questions with a red border. I think the correct way to go about this is to filter them out in the blade template.